# Firebase Android getValue(class) doesn't work

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So this is my bind model class:

```
public class UserBanknoteAmountBindModel {
    public String id;
    public String userId;
    public String banknoteType;
    public String banknoteAmount;

    public UserBanknoteAmountBindModel(){

    }

    public String getBanknoteAmount() {
        return banknoteAmount;
    }

    public String getBanknoteType() {
        return banknoteType;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setBanknoteAmount(String banknoteAmount) {
        this.banknoteAmount = banknoteAmount;
    }

    public void setBanknoteType(String banknoteType) {
        this.banknoteType = banknoteType;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

(idk if acess modifiers matter in this case).
I am trying to parse my data:

```
      for (DataSnapshot banknoteAmount:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
           UserBanknoteAmountBindModel userBanknoteAmountBindModel=dataSnapshot.getValue(UserBanknoteAmountBindModel.class);

Log.wtf("hgfh", banknoteAmount.getValue().toString());
              }
```

I see that I am receiving my data because I can log it.

> {banknoteAmount=3, banknoteType=20_dollar,
>   userId=112371098270685247195}

Anyway my data doesn't get inside my bind model. I read somewhere that I need not only to provide getters but also setters (that's why I put those setters PS: Is the thing for the setters true?).
Any ideas?

EDIT: Database Structure https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5Hgp.png
PS: The problem was that I was using the parameter from another function for the getValue (not the foorloop variable)

Comment: Please add your database structure and the entire code that you are using to get data.

Comment: @AlexMamo check the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the values of `banknoteAmount`, `banknoteType` and `userId`, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userBanknoteAmountRef = rootRef.child("userBanknoteAmount");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            UserBanknoteAmountBindModel userBanknoteAmountBindModel = ds.getValue(UserBanknoteAmountBindModel.class);
            String banknoteAmount = userBanknoteAmountBindModel.getBanknoteAmount();
            String banknoteType = userBanknoteAmountBindModel.getBanknoteType();
            String userId = userBanknoteAmountBindModel.getUserId();
            Log.d("TAG", banknoteAmount + " / " + banknoteType + " / " + userId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userBanknoteAmountRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
3 / 20_dollar / 112371098270685247195
```

When you are using the following line of code:

```
banknoteAmount.getValue().toString()
```

You are actually printing the String representation of `banknoteAmount.getValue()` which has as a return value a `Map` object which contains those three values.

Comment: I still don't get where my problem is... And yes I know that I am printing the string representation

Comment: when I debug it I see that my bindmodel is empty

Comment: In your code you have this line of code: `UserBanknoteAmountBindModel userBanknoteAmountBindModel=dataSnapshot.getValue(UserBanknoteAmountBindModel.class);` and should be `UserBanknoteAmountBindModel userBanknoteAmountBindModel=banknoteAmount.getValue(UserBanknoteAmountBindModel.class);`.

Comment: lol haha managed to figure it out before I saw your message :P